# Is there any alternative for na.replace in which data types of string being replaced and replacement can be different?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

I want to get the null fields from df to my json and in doing so have used na.fill method to fill up the null values with a string "null" and then using na.replace for replacing "null" -> null , but unfortunately data types to both the string being replaced and the replacement should be same :( so am looking for any alternative for this...any suggestions?

```scala
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("app").getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._
    val sc = spark.sparkContext

    var df = spark.read.json("/Users/sanyam/ScalaTest/a.json")

    println("----df----")
    df.show(false)

    val json = df.na.fill("null").toJSON

    val json1 = json.na.replace("*",ImmutableMap.of("null", null))

    println("****")
    json1.show(false)

  }
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameNaFunctions.html#replace

explicit null is not allowed as a replacement for string("null") in na.replace